# Bad Object Array seen in Netty

Tags: memory-leaks, netty

Our system has a memory usage issue on a Java application on version openjdk 11.0.7. Based on jxray report of the memory dump, I see two chunks of memories were not seen after the application was started initially:

`
18,576Kb (17.1%): Object[]: 9,216 / 100% of empty 18,576Kb (17.1%)

```
↖io.netty.util.internal.shaded.org.jctools.queues.MpscArrayQueue.buffer
   ↖io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$SubPageMemoryRegionCache.queue
    ↖io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache[]
      ↖io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.tinySubPageHeapCaches
        ↖j.l.r.Finalizer.referent
           ↖j.l.r.Finalizer.{next}
             ↖Java Static java.lang.ref.Finalizer.unfinalized

5,031Kb (4.6%): Object[]: 2,496 / 100% of empty 5,031Kb (4.6%)
    ↖io.netty.util.internal.shaded.org.jctools.queues.MpscArrayQueue.buffer
      ↖io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$SubPageMemoryRegionCache.queue
        ↖io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache[]
          ↖io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.tinySubPageDirectCaches
            ↖io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.cache
              ↖io.netty.util.Recycler$DefaultHandle.value
                ↖io.netty.util.Recycler$DefaultHandle[]
                  ↖io.netty.util.Recycler$WeakOrderQueue$Link.elements
                    ↖io.netty.util.Recycler$WeakOrderQueue.tail
                      ↖{j.u.WeakHashMap}.values
                      ↖Object[]
                      ↖io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap.indexedVariables
                      ↖io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalThread.threadLocalMap
                      ↖j.l.Thread[]
                      ↖j.l.ThreadGroup.threads
                      ↖org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Log4jThreadFactory.group
                      ↖j.u.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.threadFactory
                      ↖Java Static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.executor`
```

Is this a known issue?